# Man page highlight color

Tags: colors, less, highlighting

To colorize my man pages, I put this [code from archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/man_page#Using_less_.28Recommended.29) into .bashrc:

```
man() {
    env LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;38;5;74m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[38;5;246m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[04;38;5;146m' \
    man "$@"
}
```

It works okay, except when I search with `/`, the matches change colors to be even more obscure -- the opposite of highlighted. I spent some time trying to figure this out, but I can't really make sense of it, so if I do anything, it'll just be trial and error. Better to ask the experts. So how can I get search matches to be, say, black on yellow, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search patterns in `less` are colorize according to standout mode setting, so in order to display black on yellow you need to put

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[30;43m'
```

where `30` means black foreground, and `43` yellow background.

Answer (score 5):

See `man termcap` for the full definition of the variables that you are exporting. For example, this excerpt covers starting and ending standout mode: the value that is used for highlighting searches:

> se   End standout mode
>      ...
>        so   Start standout mode

You can set yellow on a black background in your standout mode like so:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;33;03;40m'
```

It is worth noting that you don't need to export these variables in every shell, you can move this function to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` to load them when you log in and they will persist.

Comment: Many thanks for the `~/.profile ` tip.

Comment: Is this even correct: `export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;33;03;40m'`, specifically the `03;` portion? I see nothing about mode or color "03" in: `man console_codes`.