# Make Less highlight search patterns instead of italicizing them

Tags: man, less, escape-characters

To my understanding man uses `less` as a pager, and when searching for keywords using `less` it "highlights" keywords with italics. I find that really inconvenient, so I'd like to change this to something like vim's `set hlsearch` where the found pattern  has a different background.

I attempted to run `man -P vim systemd` but that quit with error status 1, so it looks like I'm stuck with `less`.

There was nothing that I was able to find in `man less` that helped (instead I found out that option `-G` will turn off highlighting all together which is even worse than italics).

That being said does anyone know how to achieve search highlighting (change background color) in man pages?

FYI I run Ubuntu 14.10

I came across this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169952/man-page-highlight-color) seems to ask about the same thing but I am not sure if I follow how does this work (`LESS_TERMCAP_so`). The `less` man page does not mention this. (I get strange results with this solution)

Comment: It means you place that line in your `~/.bashrc` file. `export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[30;43m'` See this answer as well http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-without-clearing-the-screen

Comment: Sometime I use `man man | vim -` to take advantage of my vim configuration, keys and functions

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? I have the exact same problem on one machine, and I can't figure out what's the difference. Above `LESS_TERMCAP_so` variable causes the whole file to turn into orange background...

Comment: I'm afraid I am still struggling with this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found an answer over on the superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/566082/less-doesnt-highlight-search

Looks like it has to do with your TERM setting. For example, less highlighting acts normally (white background highlight) when in a normal gnome-terminal window, but when I'm in tmux, italics happens. The difference for me is that TERM is being set to "screen" when in tmux, but "xterm-256color" when not. When I set "TERM=xterm-256color" in the tmux window, highlighting in less goes back to background highlighting.

Comment: I already managed to forget about this question but this is exciting news. As soon as I get my hand on the computer I will test this out!

Comment: this is an impractical solution, because other applications depend on TERM being set to screen* when within tmux, such as WeeChat. When not set to screen* in tmux, WeeChat has weird rendering issues.

Comment: I've noted that I had the problem with tmux <2.0 and don't have the problem since tmux v2.

Comment: Great finding. I now have `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` in my *~/.tmux.conf* on my CentOS 7 box (and others).

Comment: Check also to see if `screen-256color` exists: try `ls /usr/share/terminfo/s/`.

Answer (score 15):

The mention of `LESS_TERMCAP_so` was incomplete.  That is less's special environment variable used to override the termcap `so` (standout) capability.  To use this capability, you have to provide a `se` (standend) capability as well.

The [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page gives a summary of these features for terminfo (smso/rmso) and termcap (so/se) names:

```
   enter_standout_mode           smso       so        begin standout mode
   exit_standout_mode            rmso       se        exit standout mode
```

Its section on [highlighting](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Highlighting_-Underlining_-and-Visible-Bells) explains:

> If  your  terminal  has  one  or  more  kinds  of  display
>   attributes, these can be represented in a number  of  different ways.  You should choose one display form as ***standout*** mode, representing a good, high contrast, easy-on-the-eyes,  format  for  highlighting  error messages and other
>   attention getters.  (If you have a choice,  reverse  video
>   plus  half-bright  is  good, or reverse video alone.)  The
>   sequences to enter and exit standout  mode  are  given  as
>   **`smso`**  and  **`rmso`**, respectively.

If you want to use color for *standout*, you have to provide a corresponding `LESS_TERMCAP_se` which resets color.  This is relatively simple to do as long as you do not expect to use colors in the manual page for other reasons (such as using groff's SGR color feature).

Assuming the value suggested in a comment:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[30;43m'
```

then you could reset that for most terminals using

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[39;49m'
```

By the way, the reason for the *italics* is that the terminal description for GNU `screen` uses the standard escape sequence for italics as its own standout/standend capabilities.  Some of that is discussed in the [terminal database entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Screen).

Comment: This was the first solution that actually worked for me (in tmux on a Mac). I just add both of the above export line into my bash config file.

Comment: However if I write "export" to view all my environment variables everything after these lines becomes highlighted and the terminal keeps being highlighted so I have to close it down and start a new one.

Comment: In cases like that, I put the variables into a script which calls the program that needs the particular variables.  The altered variables only apply within the script.

Comment: `export | less` functions as a workaround too

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to turn off search highlighting in `less` after a search; a new search will turn it on again, so to permanently turn search highlighting off for a session hit <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Alternately put `LESS='-G'` in your environment, or run `man` like so:

```
LESS='-G' man less
```

Ironically this is all documented in the `less` manpage...

You can also put the following in the environment, e.g. in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export MANPAGER='less -G'
```

Comment: as I explained in my question I don't want to turn it of completly, I want to change how it appears on my screen.

My question might have been misleading bacuse someone edited it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For *tmux* I set `TERM` to *tmux-256color*.
Amongst other nice things,
this has the "usual" reverse highlighting in *less*.
Works well when using something modern like fedora, or cygwin.

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
⋮
set-option -g default-terminal tmux-256color
```

The *ncurses* packages on Centos however do not have the two tmux definitions (*tmux* and *tmux-256color*).
I imported them quite easily from fedora.
Slight wrinkle is that Centos' *ncurses* is too old to understand fedora's terminfo files directly.

On fedora:

```
$ infocmp tmux256-color >temp.txt
```

On Centos:

```
$ scp fedora-machine:temp.txt .
$ tic temp.txt
```

Then inside *tmux*:

```
$ TERM=tmux-256-color man tmux
```

Result!

FYI the *tic* command puts the compiled terminal description into your personal terminfo database,
i.e.,
`~/.terminfo/t/tmux-256color` (in this case).
Feel free to move this to the global database if that's what you want:

```
$ sudo mv ~/.terminfo/t/tmux-256color /usr/share/terminfo/t/
```